# WSO2 api manager - API State Change workflow - ERROR - neither in same process nor in parent process errorCode='REST_CLIENT_INVOKE_ERROR')

Tags: wso2, ibm-api-management, wso2-appm

Im trying to configure an api state change workflow for WSO2 API manager using Integration/BPS server. When the admin finally 'approves' the publish api request as 'complete' then the BPS server fails with the following error. using API manager 2.x with Integration/BPS server 6.x Please let me know if what I could be missing..

> TID: [-1234] [] [2018-11-02 19:31:43,692] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.bpmn.rest.common.provider.ExceptionMapper.BPMNExceptionHandler}
>   -  Activiti Exception Occured  {org.wso2.carbon.bpmn.rest.common.provider.ExceptionMapper.BPMNExceptionHandler}
>   org.activiti.engine.delegate.BpmnError: No catching boundary event
>   found for error with errorCode 'REST_CLIENT_INVOKE_ERROR', neither in
>   same process nor in parent process
>   (errorCode='REST_CLIENT_INVOKE_ERROR')
>   (errorCode='REST_CLIENT_INVOKE_ERROR')
>       at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.helper.ErrorPropagation.propagateError(ErrorPropagation.java:82)
>       at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.helper.ErrorPropagation.propagateError(ErrorPropagation.java:60)
>       at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.helper.ClassDelegate.execute(ClassDelegate.java:160)
>       at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationActivityExecute.execute(AtomicOperationActivityExecute.java:60)
>       at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:97)
>       at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:644)
>       at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:637)
>       at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerStart.eventNotificationsCompleted(AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerStart.java:52)
>       at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:56)
>       at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:97)
>       at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:644)
>       at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:637)